# Matrix inversion lemma

Tags: matrices, proof-explanation

I'm currently reading a paper where they use the matrix inversion lemma in a proof and I don't understand how they are applying it. The paper is [ref](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1411.0306v3.pdf) and the proof is in Appendix A (page 13) (see image [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kqe31.png)). I don't really understand the steps, but I'm stuck at the first one which is:

$ L = RR^T(RR^T+\gamma I)^{-1}\\
\;\: = I - \gamma(RR^T+\gamma I)^{-1}$

They're supposedly using the MIL but I can't manage to reproduce it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just the distributive law.

$$I = (RR^T + \gamma I)(RR^T + \gamma I)^{-1} = RR^T (RR^T + \gamma I)^{-1} + \gamma (RR^T + \gamma I)^{-1} $$

Now subtract $\gamma (RR^T +\gamma I)^{-1}$ from both sides.